# jquery datatables setup

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am attempting to set up the jquery datatables plug in, however, I have run in to a brick wall.The following is where I have got to so far...
I have created a page called "testtable.php" the following is it's content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cloudone Chart Of Accounts</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php"


    } );
} );

        </script>
        <link href="css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<table width="101%" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="32%" scope="col">Rendering Engine;</th>
    <th width="28%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>engine</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Using the samples provided by datatables.net I have created a second page called "server_processing.php" filled in the required connection settings and put it with "testtable.php" on the testing server.
I'm using the basic configuration as outlined by datatables.net, just to get things up and running so I can have a play around to familiarise myself with the workings.This is where I am stumped, I cannot get the page to render the results. I suspecty ommiting something in the connection as well as the process for defining variables to display in the display page "testtable.php".

Can anyone point out where it is I am going astray or reference a step by step set-up example for jquery datatables server side processing.

Thank's
        David

Comment: I would suggest you first try it without serverside processing, so remove the 3 options you have now, and just put your  data on the testtable.php page

Comment: Hi That's not a bad idea, could you give a quick example of the data to include on the page ? and would this be in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started without serverside processing (if you don't have too many rows that should be fine)

create your html page just like you do now bu fill the table with your data

so:

```
<table width="101%" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="32%" scope="col">Rendering Engine;</th>
            <th width="28%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            <th width="10%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>engine</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>engine1</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>engine1</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then simply initialize datatables without any options.

See this for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/V97jd/